# (PHP - MYSQL) I want to count "likes". When they click on a button it adds 1 like

Tags: php, mysql, dao

this is my dao file

```
<?php

require_once( __DIR__ . '/DAO.php');

class insertVoteDAO extends DAO {

  public function insertVote1() {
      $sql = "UPDATE `ic_items` SET `flames`+1 WHERE id=1";
      $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute();
      return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      }
    }
?>
```

and in my index.php I do this:

```
 <?php
require_once( __DIR__ . '/dao/insertVoteDAO.php');
$voteDAO = new insertVoteDAO();

      if (!empty($_POST)) {
      $insertVote = $voteDAO->insertVote1();
    }
     ?>
```

This is the error I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '+1 WHERE id=1' at line 1 in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/backend/major-IC/dao/insertVoteDAO.php:9
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/backend/major-IC/dao/insertVoteDAO.php(9):
>   PDO->prepare('UPDATE `ic_item...') #1
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/backend/major-IC/collection.php(72):
>   insertVoteDAO->insertVote1() #2 {main} thrown in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/backend/major-IC/dao/insertVoteDAO.php on
>   line 9

It says I do something wrong with syntax in my query.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: check for errors, then update your post to contain what they are, if any and using proper error handling methods.

Comment: "It doens't work" is not a problem description.

Comment: Your error message say: You have a syntax error in your SQL syntax. +1 seems wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add plus one (+1) to a SQL Server column in a SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370088/how-to-add-plus-one-1-to-a-sql-server-column-in-a-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong at `flames`+1:

$sql = "UPDATE `ic_items` SET `flames`+1 WHERE id=1";

It should be

$sql = "UPDATE `ic_items` SET `flames` = `flames`+1 WHERE id=1";

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with BanNsS1, 
you can check the following link for further reference: [Increment a database field by 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762851/increment-a-database-field-by-1#2762856)